# How to convert JSON into an array or string?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to ask these types of questions. Anyway, I have this array value `$custom_fields['user_gender'][0]` that outputs this:

`a:2:{i:0;s:7:"Male";i:1;s:7:"Female";}`

I'm not sure how to convert this into an array or string.

Comment: I assume you use PHP?

Comment: You might be allowed if you make your question a little bit more clear. Such as on which language do you want to use it? I am guessing php, am I right?

Comment: Sorry guys. Yes, it's PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example data looks like it is [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) PHP. Serializing is a way an array, string etc. can be "represented" as a textual string and can later be converted back to the original data format, using a unserialize operation. A serialized string can be stored as text in a database and can be unserialized at any point.

You can [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it with:

```
$array = unserialize($custom_fields['user_gender'][0]);
```

This should return an array. If you `var_dump` on $`array`, you can be sure it's an array.

Comment: Will accept this answer in a few mins. Anyway, it outputs this `array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Male" [1]=> string(6) "Female" }` how do I let it show only Male and Female?

Comment: Yes it is an array. You can use `$array[0]` for male and `$array[1]` for female.

Comment: I have a follow up question. I did this: `$user_gender = unserialize($custom_fields['user_gender'][0]);` And then I did this `$user_gender = array_map('strtolower', $user_gender);` But I get this error 'Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array'

Comment: As the error tells, `$user_gender` is not an array, it is a string. If you just want to lowercase the string just use `strtolower($user_gender)` instead. The `array_map` would apply that function to every string in array, but using it on a string is not going to work.